# Advantages of using screen reader text

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have seen some web templates that have html tags named **Screen Reader Text** like bellow:

```
<label for="name" class="screen-reader-text">Name:</label>
```

And its CSS will be:

```
.screen-reader-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: -999em;
    left:-999em;
}
```

But nothing is showed in my PC browser. What is it?
Regards.

Comment: You do understand that a "screen reader" is what visually impaired users use to read the webpage to them, right?  (some users with comprehension difficulties use them, too).

Comment: Yes, And you mean it will be used for more help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual browsers will hide that content since the CSS essentially places it off of the screen. Screen readers will ignore that CSS and read the content normally. Basically, this site is attempting to make the page visually appealing while making is accessible to visually impaired users.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi I think you should look up what a [screen reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) is.

Answer (score 2):

The *tag* here is the `label` tag. The element is defined as belonging to the class `screen-reader-text`. There is no magic in the name. It is just an assigned name, and could be `foobar` too. The style sheet defines that an element in that class be positioned outside the browser window.

This is bad practice, since `label` markup and labels of controls are useful to all users, not just users of speech browsers, which ignore the attempts to place something off screen.

There could be special reasons for the coding, but they cannot be guessed from the information given.

Comment: Information like the context of the element. It presumably associates with a control. Is the purpose of the control somehow evident from the visual presentation of the page?